# ARC with non-Foundation Objects

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, clang

I have made my own Objective-C base class to use in Objective-C projects (without Foundation/Cocoa classes or API). While I don't mind writing my own retains and releases, it's a tedious process so I'm wondering if I can use ARC with my custom classes.

Specifically:

- Is it possible to use ARC with custom classes?
- Do my reference-counting selectors have to be called `retain` and `release` (and `autorelease`)?
- What additional requirements are there to make ARC work as expected for custom classes (other than including the `-fobjc-arc` argument when compiling)?

Comment: Let me rephrase your question.  You're trying to make your own root class with ARC???

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. All ARC does is puts in retains and releases, which your root class has to implement. Are you seeing problems? If so, what problems?

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Yep, it works with standard retain-release calls. Getting ARC working will make future work much lighter though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using your own root class?

Comment: @NSResponder Eventually portability to Windows is the main goal, now that GCC (in MinGW) contains a reasonable ObjC2.0 runtime.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the GnuStep foundation?

Comment: @NSResponder I could have, but I thought it would be an interesting project to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use ARC with custom classes?

Of course it is.

> Do my reference-counting selectors have to be called retain and release (and autorelease)?

Yes, they do. Apple has hardcoded the method names of its favorite Objective-C library (Foundation) into the compiler. Damn bad programming pattern, isn't it?

> What additional requirements are there to make ARC work as expected for custom classes (other than including the -fobjc-arc argument when compiling)?

As far as I know, nothing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, thanks :). I wondered if the retain/release names were hard-coded... I know they did it with the new container syntax... Ah well.

Comment: @PLPiper yep, also `@[]` and `@{}` translates to a hard-coded selector name... **What a shame!**

Comment: You can see the hardcoding of selector names in here - http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-arr.mm . Look at `objc_retain` for example. Also look at `objc_rootRetain` which is what `NSObject` and `NSProxy` use to handle reference counting.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm getting the subtle feeling that non-conformist programming is discouraged... Could be just me though..!

Comment: @PLPiper non-conformist to what?

Comment: @mattjgalloway Ah thank you for the link. Liking their 'msgSend_hack' calls! I'd seen a slightly different objc_rootRetain [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm) at the moment I'm not deep enough in to differentiate between a retain and a rootRetain, so just using a basic hashtable for the time being.

Comment: @H2CO3 Using Foundation classes, generally, I've noticed in several places the comment that all classes must inherit from NSObject, or similar encouragement. I have nothing against Foundation - I use it all the time! - but I thought this could be an interesting side-project.

Comment: @PLPiper Of course I use it too, but hardcoding a root class, a method name, or anything else to a compiler and to a language (even NSConstantString is part of this pattern!) is a terrible practice.

Comment: @H2CO3 Very true. I'm rather grateful for the `-fconstant-string-class=` flag. Just wish there were `-fdictionary-class=` or `-fretain-sel=`, etc, flags as well.

Comment: @PLPiper Yes, exactly! The language specification (Euhm, Objective-C doesn't have a standard like C and C++ have) should contain that "the underlying classes for the '@"", @<number>, @{} and @[]` constructs are to be specified at compile-time by the user and may have a vendor-specific default value that can be modified"...

Comment: Thanks to the memory management naming convention we don't need to add qualifiers everywhere. Whoever wants the hassle of following an alternative convention needs to tell the compiler with NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED, etc. Rather them than me doing the extra work.